# How to filter twilio messages after a certain time

Tags: twilio

I want to process only Twilio SMS messages that are received after my service has started. I am not able to get the code working in python. Please help.

I wonder if even this snippet is correct as well. It was copied from else where into my code.

Here is my python code. I am new to python.

```
messages = TwilioClient.messages.list(date_sent=datetime.datetime.utcnow())

for p in messages:
  sSMSSender = p.from_

if p.date_updated < date_sent:
  continue
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Megan from Twilio here.

The `DateSent` parameter is returned in RFC 2822 format. 
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#instance

```
Mon, 11 April 2016 15:52:01 +0000
```

Thus you will have to do a little extra work to separate time out this data. You can give it a try in a [spreadsheet](https://github.com/devinrader/TwilioSheet/blob/master/README.md).

Hope this helps.